# How to transfer the integer values from one Java file to other Java file in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to transfer an integer value from one Java file to other file. I am, however, having difficulties. This is MainActivity.java file:

```
    package com.e.krishna;               
    import android.os.Bundle;    
    import android.app.Activity;   
    import android.content.Intent;    
    import android.view.View;    
    import android.widget.Button;  
    import android.widget.TextView;   
    public class MainActivity extends Activity    
{   
    protected static final String KEY = null;   
    TextView display1;   
    TextView display2;   
    Button btn;   
           int counter=0;   
           int a;    
    public void onCreate( Bundle a1) {    
        super.onCreate(a1);    
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
        display1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tView);     
        display2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tView1);     
                btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);    
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()                   
{    
                 public void onClick(View v)     {     
                         Intent inf=newIntent(MainActivity.this,Images.class);    
                                startActivity(inf);              
                                                                            }    
                Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();            
        {        
            a = bundle.getInt("a");         
            display1.setText("your count is "+a);                   
        };              
    });            
}    
}
```

This is Images.java

```
    package com.e.hare_krishna;    
    import android.app.Activity;    
    import android.content.Intent;    
   import android.os.Bundle;    
   import android.view.View;    
     import android.widget.Button;    
    import android.widget.TextView;    
  public class Images extends Activity      
{    
   private static final String KEY = null;    
   Button btn;    
   public static int a;    
  int i;    
  TextView display1;    
  public void onCreate(Bundle a1)    
 {    
    super.onCreate(a1);    
    setContentView(R.layout.image);    
    display1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tView1);    
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);    
    a=0;    
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
     public void onClick(View v) {         
                    a++;    
            display1.setText("your count is "+a);    

     }    
    });    

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);    
    intent.putExtra(KEY,  a);    
    startActivity(intent);    


}    
}
```

I tried this code but the 'a' value does not get displayed. From the second Java file the value of 'a' should be passed to mainactivity and get displayed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please go through  basic android components http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

## In Main Activity Try this :-

int a = getIntent.getIntExtra(KEY, 0);

Should work..

Answer (score 0):

You declare a key `private static final String KEY = null;` and then you store a value like this `intent.putExtra(KEY,  a);`

But you have to use the same key like this :

1) store your value

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);    
intent.putExtra("MY_KEY",  a);    
startActivity(intent);
```

2) retrieve your value under NewActivity.class

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("MY_KEY");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String KEY = "val";    

//Pass like this
Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);    
intent.putExtra(KEY,  a);    
startActivity(intent); 

//Get like this

Intent intent = getIntent();
int a = intent.getIntExtra("val", 0);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's original question, a few lines of explanation will help current and future readers understand your question even better.

Answer (score 0):

Your KEY is null, you should give it a String value in both activities (make sure it's the same in both)
for example KEY = "number" or any string you want